# GT-I9001 (galaxy S plus) not recognized in Windows 8.1

Tags: cyanogenmod, clockworkmod-recovery, bootloader, odin

I installed the ClockworkMod Recovery v6.0.1.4 and tried to install a cyanogen mod on my Galaxy S plus (GT-I9001), but now my phone is stuck in a reboot-loop where the OS doesn't start and I just come back to the ClockworkMod screen.

I tried putting it into "download mode" and linking it via usb to my Win8.1 laptop (I was going to use Odin to install a new bootloader) but Windows says "USB Samsung Composite device - failed to load" and won't show in Odin. One weird things is that if I use another version of Odin (Odin3 v3.09) and I leave the phone usb connected in the CWM screen, Odin3 detects it, although afterwards is uncapable of carrying out the re-flash.

I'm a newbie with phone rooting and mod installing and I wanted some help on how to get my phone out of the reboot-lock into CWM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the latest Samsung drivers. Uninstall all previous Samsung drivers, and try to use a lower windows version like W7. W8.1 is still full of weirdness, especially when mixing 32bit and 64bit software.